# Multiple signals in main, signals to text

Tags: signals, elm

I just got into Elm and I'm stuck at a problem that on first sight looks quite simple but I'm struggling with finding what's the best practice to tackle the problem.

**The exercise:**

Write a program that shows three text fields, arranged vertically. The first shows the current mouse position and True or False depending on whether the left mouse button is currently down. The second text box is shown below the first and shows True or False depending on whether or not the space bar is down. Finally, the third text field shows the current value of Keyboard.arrows. Play with the resulting program so that you understand the behaviour of all these input signals.

**My code:**

```
import Keyboard
import Mouse
import Html exposing ( Html )

main = 
  Signal.map mapStringToHtml position,
  Signal.map mapStringToHtml mouseDown,
  Signal.map mapStringToHtml spaceDown,
  Signal.map mapStringToHtml arrows

mapStringToHtml : String -> Html
mapStringToHtml x = Html.text x

position : Signal String
position = Signal.map toString Mouse.position

mouseDown : Signal String
mouseDown = Signal.map toString Mouse.isDown

spaceDown : Signal String
spaceDown = Signal.map toString Keyboard.space

arrows : Signal String
arrows = Signal.map toString Keyboard.arrows
```

My main doesn't compile but I don't know how else I need to do it. Am I on the right path? Could it be shorter? How can I use the architecture model, view, update in this case?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Minimally invasive

You could go full Elm Architecture, but since this seems to be a learning exercise, let me give you the smallest change to get it working:

```
main =
  Signal.map4 combineHtml
    (Signal.map mapStringToHtml position)
    (Signal.map mapStringToHtml mouseDown)
    (Signal.map mapStringToHtml spaceDown)
    (Signal.map mapStringToHtml arrows)

combineHtml pos mouse space arr =
  Html.div [] [pos, mouse, space, arr]

mapStringToHtml : String -> Html
mapStringToHtml x = Html.div [] [Html.text x]
```

So each piece of text is in its own div. `combineHtml` combines all those by putting them in another div. I figured that's the easiest way to quickly get them all on a separate line.

To combine *signals* of divs into one, we use [`Signal.map4`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Signal#map4). It takes a function that takes four arguments, and four signals. Every time one of the signals updates, the function is evaluated with the latest values from the signal.

## Rewrite

The minimal change treated all information the same and put them all on a separate line. But the question includes that mouse position and button should be on the same line. So here's a rewrite of the program that also has a little bit less code duplication:

```
import Keyboard
import Mouse
import Html exposing ( Html )

main = Signal.map4 view
  Mouse.position
  Mouse.isDown
  Keyboard.space
  Keyboard.arrows

view position mouseDown spaceDown arrows =
  let
    div  = Html.div []
    text = toString >> Html.text
    spacer = Html.text " "
  in
    div
      [ div [ text position, spacer, text mouseDown ]
      , div [ text spaceDown ]
      , div [ text arrows ]
      ]
```

The `let`-`in` construct defines some local constants. `div` is a shortcut for `Html.div` where the first argument is always an empty list. `text` is a function that first applies `toString` and on the result of that applies `Html.text`. So long-form of those functions is:

```
    div children = Html.div [] children
    text something = Html.text (toString something)
    -- or as pipeline: text something = something |> toString |> Html.text
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer but the only thing that's missing is that position must be next to mouseDown. I guess to achieve that I would only need to change the combineHtml method.